# Running Wusa.exe /uninstall with Start-Process not working

Tags: windows, powershell, updates, uninstallation, start-process

I have been trying to uninstall an update via powershell.  I am trying to leverage wusa.exe using start-process. When i pass the uninstall and quiet switches it fails to run. I get this error in setup event logs:

```
Windows update  could not be uninstalled because of error 2147942487 "The parameter is incorrect." (Command line: ""C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe" /KB:4512516 /uninstall  /quiet /norestart ")
```

I've read you have to do this differently with Windows 10 but I can't find any examples.  How can I run this?  If  I run it without silent it pops up the window to uninstall the update with no issues.

Here is what i am trying to run.

```
Start-Process -FilePath wusa.exe -ArgumentList "/uninstall /KB:4512516 /quiet /norestart" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait
```

Comment: 1) The `-ArgumentList` parameter to `Start-Process` is an array. 2) You don't need `Start-Process` to run a command. Just type the command and press `Enter`: `wusa /kb:4512516 /uninstall /quiet /norestart`

Comment: Windows update  could not be uninstalled because of error 2147942487 "The parameter is incorrect." (Command line: ""C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe" /kb:4512516 /uninstall /quiet /norestart")    same thing.  Im using this in a script so would like to be able to use the - wait parameter with start-process

Comment: I guess you just cant use quiet with wusa.exe /uninstall. i see so many people trying to use that i thought you could but its not shown in the help file.  Need to uninstall updates remotely so not sure how i can bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

Found Remove-Windowspackage cmdlet which is a native cmdlet in powershell. Using that instead.